# Bind classes with Alpine but based on value of variable, not boolean

Tags: alpine.js

OK, so, I'm probably barking up the wrong tree, but I'm lost in the forest anyway.

I'm trying to sort out class binding so I can toggle classes in a checkout's navigation bar to where the user is in the checkout.

There are three checkout steps (billing, payment method and payment) and each of the three can be 'inactive', 'active', or 'done'. Assume, when the page loads, that all the billing information is already complete, so billing would be done, the payment method step would be active, and the payment step would be inactive. The container therefore looks like :

```
<main x-data="{b:'done', pm:'active', p:'inactive' }">
```

Within an individual step I am trying to use the value of each variable in class binding like so :

```
<i class="text-4xl" :class="pm='inactive' ? 'fal fa-circle-xmark text-gray-500' : ''" :class="pm='active' ? 'fal fa-pen-circle text-indigo-500' : ''" :class="pm='done' ? 'fal fa-circle-check text-green-500' : ''"></i>
```

But it's not working - if it were, for the payment method step I'd be seeing an indigo pen icon, but I'm seeing the 'inactive' grey circle-xmark icon.

Where am I going wrong? And can I simplify the  tag rather than use three ternary operators?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so, I was being a bit of a muppet. Needed "==" rather than just "=" in the comparator section of the ternary operator. And yes, you can nest the ternary clause :

```
<i class="text-4xl" :class="pm=='inactive' ? 'fal fa-circle-xmark text-gray-500' : ''" :class="pm=='active' ? 'fal fa-pen-circle text-indigo-500' : ''" :class="pm=='done' ? 'fal fa-circle-check text-green-500' : ''"></i>
```